# Socket server build issue

Tags: java, sockets, build

The socket server listed in step 3 from http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html builds cleanly (java version "1.7.0_02") and runs without error but it exits without error instead of waiting to accept clients.

**Updated ChatServer with missing arg code:**

**ChatServer:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{  private ServerSocket     server = null;
   private Thread           thread = null;
   private ChatServerThread client = null;

   public ChatServer(int port)
   {  try
      {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
         server = new ServerSocket(port);
         System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
         start();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println(ioe); }
   }
   public void run()
   {  while (thread != null)
      {  try
         {  System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
            addThread(server.accept());
         }
         catch(IOException ie)
         {  System.out.println("Acceptance Error: " + ie); }
      }
   }
   public void addThread(Socket socket)
   {  System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
      client = new ChatServerThread(this, socket);
      try
      {  client.open();
         client.start();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println("Error opening thread: " + ioe); }
   }
   public void start() {
   thread = new Thread(this);
   thread.start();
 }
   public void stop()                    { /* no change */ }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ChatServer server = null;
      if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatServer port");
      else
         server = new ChatServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
 }
}
```

**ChatServerThread:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ChatServer      server   = null;
   private int             ID       = -1;
   private DataInputStream streamIn =  null;

   public ChatServerThread(ChatServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {  server = _server;  socket = _socket;  ID = socket.getPort();
   }
   public void run()
   {  System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      while (true)
      {  try
         {  System.out.println(streamIn.readUTF());
         }
         catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {  streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: `builds cleanly but does not run` Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Yes, no compilation errors, when executed it should spawn a listener and wait for client connections, but it does not, it instead seems to disappear, no errors. Step one on the referenced page does work though.

Comment: Try to handle the IOException in ChatServerThread run method, and print the error. If the client closes the socket you will have an infinite loop there an you wouldn't notice because the exception is not handled.

Comment: Added recommendation to ChatServerThread per suggested answer below. Still not receiving an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updating my answer with a working solution.

Change these methods in your `ChatServer` class in order to be like these

```
public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() { 
    // You should implement this too
}

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    // Instantiate a CharServer with the listening port 9191
    ChatServer chatServer = new ChatServer(9191);
    // CharServer.start() should not be confused with Thread.start();
    // This calls our custom method up above, which includes a call to
    // Thread(ChatServer).start();
    chatServer.start();

}
```

Where 9191 is a port number I made up.

Executing `CharServer`#main method produces the following output and stays alive

```
Binding to port 9191, please wait  ...
Server started: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=9191]
Waiting for a client ...
Waiting for a client ...
```

You should also implement `stop()` method for the sake of functionality.

Comment: @Astron I have updated my answer with a proper solution. Please check it.

Comment: Per you solution I realized that the args were not present in the example. I will update the question with the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {  while (thread != null)
```

You never set thread so it will all be null
And you never create a thread

Try changing start() to:

```
public void start()                   { 
   thread = new Thread(this);
   thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Changed the start() as described, same results. How should the thread be set so it is not always null?

Comment: Sorry a typo there, it should be thread = new Thread(this);  Have updated my answer